# Using personal library hosted on github as gradle dependency

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android library that is hosted on github and need to add it as a dependency to another project without manually cloning the repository and adding it as a module dependency. How do I go about creating my own gradle dependency with link from github? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you've pushed your code to GitHub then sharing your library is easy with [JitPack](https://jitpack.io).

Your users will just need to add the repository to their build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

and then your GitHub repository as dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.YourUsername:Repo:Release'
}
```

JitPack acts as a maven repository and can be used like Maven Central. The nice thing is that you don't have to upload your library. Behind the scenes JitPack will check out the code from GitHub and compile it. As you publish a new release on GitHub it becomes available for others to use.

There is also [a guide](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/) on how to prepare an Android project.

Answer (score 1):

Github is not a maven repository.
if it's "free for all" license, you can clone project and post it for example  in [jCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), then add it as gradle dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You have to release your library to a repository which can be used by Gradle. When you want the library to be publicly available you can publish it to Maven Central. See http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html#releasing-the-deployment-to-the-central-repository for details about how to publish your library from gradle to Maven Central.

Once published in Maven Central use the normal gradle dependency declaration.

Comment: what if the repository is meant to be kept private? How do I go about adding a dependency to a private github repo?

Comment: Create your own repo. It is also possible to include the poms and jars is a separate directory in your project and use that directory as a local file based repository. 
    `allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "file://" + projectDir + "/../gradle/repo" }
            maven { url "file://${System.env.ANDROID_HOME}/extras/android/m2repository" 
        }   
    }`